# Check if list of integers contains two groups of different repeated numbers

Tags: java, java-stream, frequency

How to using java stream, check if list of integers contains two groups of different repeated numbers. Number must be repeated not more then two time.

Example: list of 23243.
Answer: true, because 2233

Example 2: list of 23245.
Answer: none

Example 3: list of 23232.
Answer: none, because 222 repeated three times

One more question, how can i return not anyMatch, but the biggest of repeated number?

```
listOfNumbers.stream().anyMatch(e -> Collections.frequency(listOfNumbers, e) == 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will tell you if the list meets your requirements.

- stream the list of digits.
- do a frequency count.
- stream the resultant counts
- filter out those not equal to a count of 2.
- and count how many of those there are.

Returns true if `final count == 2`, false otherwise.

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(2,2,3,3,3,4,4);
boolean result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a,
                Collectors.counting()))
        .values().stream().filter(count -> count == 2).limit(2)
        .count() >= 2;  // fixed per OP's comment
```

The above prints `true` since there are two groups of just two digits, namely `2's` and `4's`

**EDIT**

First, I made `Holger's` suggestion to short circuit the count check.

To address your question about returning multiple values, I broke up the process into parts.  The first is the normal frequency count that I did before.  The next is gathering the information requested.  I used a `record` to return the information.  A class would also work.  The max count for some particular number is housed in an `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3);
Results results = groupCheck(list);
System.out.println(results.check);
System.out.println(results.maxEntry);
```

Prints (`getKey()` and `getValue()` may be used to get the individual values. First is the number, second is the occurrences of that number.)

```
true
3=5
```

The method and record declaration

```
record Results(boolean check,
        AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Long> maxEntry) {
}
```

Once the frequency count is computed, simply iterate over the entries and
count the pairs and compute the maxEntry by comparing the existing maximum count to the iterated one and update as required.

```
public static Results groupCheck(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a, Collectors.counting()));
    
    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Long> maxEntry =
            new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(0, 0L);
    int count = 0;
    for (Entry<Integer, Long> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() == 2) {
            count++;
        }
        maxEntry = e.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue() ?
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e) : maxEntry;
    }
    
    return new Results(count >= 2, maxEntry);
}
```

Comment: its not working if will be 3 correct groups like 2,2,3,3,4,4

Comment: You said *if list of integers contains two groups of different repeated numbers. Number must be repeated not more then two time.*  The number repeated 3 times is ignored, like you implied.  Only 2 and 4 were counted as they occurred only twice.  You need to clarify your requirement.

Comment: And you said to see if list contains **two groups of 2**, not **two or more groups of 2**.  However, I fixed it due to your comment.

Comment: When your condition is `.count() >= 2`, you can use `.limit(2).count() >= 2` to short circuit when the condition went `true` and can’t change back.

Comment: but how can return not boolean, but max number from this two group?

Answer (score 1):

One could write a method which builds a `TreeMap` of the frequencies.

What happens here, is that a frequency map is built first (by `groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`), and then we must 'swap' the keys and values, because we want to use the frequencies as keys.

```java
public static TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> frequencies(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getValue(), e -> List.of(e.getKey()), (a, b) -> someMergeListsFunction(a, b), TreeMap::new));
    }
```

And then we can just use our method like this:

```java
// We assume the input list is not empty
TreeMap<Long, List<Integer>> frequencies = frequencies(list);
var higher = frequencies.higherEntry(2L);
if (higher != null) {
    System.out.printf("There is a number which occurs more than twice: %s (occurs %s times)\n", higher.getValue().get(0), higher.getKey());
}
else {
    List<Integer> occurTwice = frequencies.lastEntry().getValue();
    if (occurTwice.size() < 2) {
        System.out.println("Only " + occurTwice.get(0) " occurs twice...");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(occurTwice);
    }
}
```

A `TreeMap` is a `Map` with keys sorted by some comparator, or the *natural order* if none is given. The `TreeMap` class contains methods to search for certain keys. For example, the `higherEntry` method returns the first entry which is higher than the given key. With this method, you can easily check if a key higher than `2` exists, for one of the requirements is that none of the numbers may occur more than twice.

The above code checks whether there is a number occurring more than twice, that is when `higherEntry(2L)` returns a nonnull value. Otherwise, `lastEntry()` is the highest number occurring. With `getValue()`, you can retrieve the list of these numbers.